# Writing to a txt file in resource folder in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filewriter, txt

I have an event trigger that is meant to write to a .txt file within my resource folder. However, nothing is being written to said resource folder. I have no idea why this will not work and would appreciate any help.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int b = numericUpDown1.GetHashCode();
        int c = numericUpDown2.GetHashCode();
        int d = numericUpDown3.GetHashCode();

        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("orders.txt");
            sw.WriteLine("Burger(s) " + b);
            sw.WriteLine("Chip(s): " + c);
            sw.WriteLine("Drink(s) " + d);
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

This problem has been resolved. The code works, I was not aware that the .txt file was inside my debug folder.

Comment: You should probably sw.Flush() before closing. Also it is good practice to use streamwriter in a using block -> using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("orders.txt") { [code utilizing sw here] }

Comment: If you're debugging, the location of orders.txt by default is inside /bin/debug

Comment: Hi plori, do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
class WriteAllLines
{
  public static async Task ExampleAsync()
{
    string[] lines =
    {
        "First line", "Second line", "Third line" 
    };

    await File.WriteAllLinesAsync("WriteLines.txt", lines);
}
```

}

from microsoft

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file)

Comment: Thanks Tayfun, I did see this I was just hoping to see also why my code doesn't work.

Comment: @brad Your code works well. order.txt in bin/debug folder.